# API for SPA - Should I load all data up front?

Tags: api, single-page-application

I'm working on a single page application app that keeps track of student activity throughout the day.

When the app loads, you get a list of classes (30 to 50). When you navigate to a class, you get a list of the class students (about 20 to 25) and other stats. Then you can navigate to each student page to see their activities.

My question is API related. Is it better to load all data up front in one request which includes all the classes and stats which include all their students which include all their stats and activities, or should I load the data on demand? List of classes on classes page, list of Class X students and stats on Class X page, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to estimate the amount of data in Kilobytes as this is the main bottleneck in mobile applications (you're building a responsive single page app, right?). The response could be in between: load classes and students upfront, then student details on click.

Then try to predict your user's behavior. Are they more concerned about a given class as a whole, their peculiar student page, etc. If classes and student list is only used as selectors to access the student page, then load as few details as possible about them until the student page.

Can your user loose their connection while using the app? In this case load as much as possible while you can.

Consider also using type ahead search boxes (auto suggest). In this case you don't have to load all the data upfront but only when an item is selected.

Comment: Thanks. Actually we're working on separate applications: desktop version and native mobile. Due to the instability of the wireless connections, the mobile version will need all the data up front to be able to work offline, so loading it that way will be a good idea. But the desktop version is a bit different. Would you recommend having similar calls with different amount of data? For example using `GET /classes` to get everything and the `GET /classes` with a parameter of students=0 to get just the list of classes?

Comment: Certainly, multiple levels of details should be specified with parameters. I don't recommend having different APIs for desktop or mobile versions.